# Bootstrap - Overlapping items inside card block

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am going crazy here. I have this piece of Html and when the screen resizes the words and labels overlap on screen resize before it gets to the col-md. Each letter goes to the next row as the screen gets resized down to the medium screen size and it looks terrible. Anyone have a clue what could be the issue here?

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2 ">
          <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-block' style="padding-left: 10px">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                      <div class="row">
                        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Radios</legend>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                              First radio
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                              Second radio
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check disabled">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                              Third disabled radio
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="form-check">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
                          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                            Example checkbox
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10 ">
             * A Grid will go here after the user signs in *     
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what purpose your nested grid serves? Also, the `col-xs-*` grid was removed in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: I just need to have it on a page. The page has 4 sections actually. The code I pasted is for the top left and right quadrants. So the top left will have the user input information. The top right will show maybe an actual grid. The bottom quadrants will show something else. My issue is Im still stuck on getting the left top quadrant to look correct.

Comment: And what version are you using? I noticed you have class names like `card-block` which doesn't seem to exist in BS4.

Comment: We were on Bootstrap 3 but have recently upgraded to bootstrap 4. I believe card block is now card-body

Comment: Given the outdated code your presenting above, I would recommend cleaning it up to at least match what Bootstrap 4 uses so we can troubleshoot an issue outside the scope of "Is the user just using the wrong classes"